# Using format_number() in $row records to display result with a separator?

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

How can I display the records just like this: *3,232,300.00* ?

I tried the code below but the output is *0.00*

```
number_format($rows['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',')
```

Comment: What does `var_dump( $rows['total_amount'] );` output?

Comment: Fix your mysqli query.

Comment: @dummydummy: Well, then, there's your problem. Figure out why it's returning NULL instead of the expected result. Probably something wrong with your database query.

Comment: @AmalMurali but when I go back to just normal code $row['total_amount'] it's display correctly, what should I do? I'm new using php.

Comment: @dummydummy: Make sure you're doing the `var_dump` inside your loop. Please show the full code.

Comment: Is it $rows['total_amount'] or $row['total_amount']?